# Read strings into dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get values by user in a dynamic allocated string array. And I'm trying to use a `for`/`while`-loop in such a way that the reading of string would end whenever the user enters the string `"!"`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string> 
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int b=1;
    int top=0;
    string * a=new string[b] ;
    cin>>a[b];
    top++;
    while(a[b]!="!")
    {
        if(top==b)
            b++;
        cin>>a[b];
        top++;
    }
```

Comment: You've allocated space for one integer. Then you access the element past the end right away and continue on after that.

Comment: You should try to ask a question.

Comment: @user3125340 The problem is still the same. You dynamically allocate 1 string (`new string[b]`) and then you attempt to read into `a[b]` which is an element that doesn't exist - `a[0]` does exist, but `a[1]` doesn't.

Comment: man I m increasing b++ using if check it

Comment: another thing if I replace int means I allocate int dynamic array it is working

Comment: @Rubens since the code triggers undefined behaviour, what is "not working" could take many forms.

Comment: @juanchopanza You're right; I didn't actually read the early comments -- was just trying to improve his post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be done musch simpler if you would use standard class std::string.
If to speak about character arrays then the approach is to allocate a character array of a fixed size. When there will be entered more characters than the size of the array then reallocate the array increasing its size and copy elements of the current array in the new one.

For example

```
const size_t N = 10;

char *s = new char[N];

char c;
size_t size = N;
size_t i = 0;

while ( std::cin >> c && c != '!' )
{
    if ( i == size - 1 )
    {
        char *p = new char[size + N];
        std::copy( s, s + size - 1, p );
        delete []s;
        s = p;
        size += N;
    }

    s[i++] = c;
}
   .

s[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: I want to use it as string not as char

Comment: There is no any sense to dynamically allocate an object of type std::string in your case. std::string itself dynamically allocates memory. Also I see that you changed the original post.

Comment: Beacuse I want multiple string in array

Comment: Thanks it helped I replaced char with string it helped :D

Answer (score 0):

Responding to the title of the question,

> “I want to get values by user in dynamic allocated string array by using for loop or while loop it would end when user enters "!"”

`std::string` is a nice way to get a dynamically allocated string, with automatic allocation and deallocation of the buffer.

`std::vector` is a nice general dynamic size array.

So, you might try something like this (off the cuff code):

```
using namespace std;
vector<string> lines;
for( ;; )
{
    string line;
    getline( cin, line );
    if( line == "!" ) { break; }
    lines.push_back( line );
}
// Do something with the lines
```

Comment: not helping I dont know what vector is :/